# Error When Making REST HTTP Request to 3rd Pary API. Possibly relate to IPv6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xmlhttprequest, ipv6, ipv4

I am trying to make some http request to a third party API using rest-client or httparty. The code Im running is:

on terminal:

```
 httparty 'http://swapi.co/api/people/1'
```

Its throwing this error:

```
/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': No route to host - connect(2) for "swapi.co" port 80 (Errno::EHOSTUNREACH)
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'
from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
```

in my app:

```
 test_data=RestClient.get('http://swapi.co/api/people/1')
```

They are throwing a similar error:

```
Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) for "swapi.co" port 80
```

from /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/http-0.9.9/lib/http/timeout/null.rb:18:in `initialize'

I think this has something to do with IP configurations, but Im not sure where to start troubleshooting.
I'd appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction on how to solve this.

Potentially Relevant Notes:
1) I've been getting this error since I updated from an older version of OSX to Sierra OSX. I did that because prior to that, my http requests (with rest-client, httparty or curl) were working but they were consistently taking 1 minute and 16 seconds for very little data.  When I do curl now, they work pretty fast, so that problem was solved.

Comment: This isn't a problem with Ruby or the clients, as the requests work for me on my system. it's most likely with your system configuration or network. I'd recommend looking on [su] and [apple.se]. Response times of 1+ minutes is a hint that the network and/or DNS aren't happy.

Comment: curl request are working now and they are not slow. The slow response issue was prior to updating to OS X Sierra. Now the difficulty is making rest request with rest-client or httparty

Comment: As I said, both rest-client and HTTParty work fine on my Mac OS system to hit that URL and return the page with sub-second response. Does your browser have the same issue loading the page? Why would IPv6 be an issue? Turn it off in your Networking and see if IPv4 works. We need more information because currently we know nothing about your system, it's configuration, or your networking connection.

Comment: Works fine for me on IPv6. Do you have IPv6 connectivity at all? If you aren't sure, you can check it at https://myip.addr.space/ (mine). It could be that your ISP has broken IPv6, or CloudFlare has broken it again, or any number of other things.

Comment: Some updates:  1) I went to starbucks today and everything worked like a charm on their connection 2) At home everything works well on my browser and in curl.  3)I ran the test, says it could not determined IPv6 address.  4) After running the test, I turned IPv6 off and now the ruby clients seem to be working as well from my home connection.  I guess this solves the problem, except that I read online that shutting off IPv6 is not ideal (excludes IPv6 internet).  Can anyone think of other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by shutting off IPv4. Not sure if that will come back to haunt me in the future, but for now that has eliminated all issues with all http request clients.